# Spinner won't respond to clicks...even though onItemSelected is called?

Tags: android

My Activity implements OnItemSelected listener for a spinner.  It has the interesting problem of firing off the onItemSelected callback when the activity shows.  So I used a flag hack to solve it (I hate it, but at this point I just want the app to work).

Strangely enough, even though the callback gets called right at activity start, my actual touch selections don't work.   I can touch the list, open it, see the strings from the array adapter, and even touch it to make it dismiss - but the callback is never called.

My code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
…
private ArrayList<String> mMyTypes = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mMyAdapter = null;
private Spinner mMyTypeSpinner = null;
// hack for spinner
boolean isFirstRunWithSpinner = true;
```

In onCreate():

```
mMyTypeSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_activity_spinner);

mMyTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
mMyTypes.add("Test string");

mMyAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner_style, mMyTypes);
mMyAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mMyTypeSpinner.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);

// spinner listener
mMyTypeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

The callback:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
 Toast
 .makeText(ConfirmEditActivity.this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show();
if( isFirstRunWithSpinner ) { isFirstRunWithSpinner = false; return; }
…
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
 Toast
 .makeText(ConfirmEditActivity.this, "Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
 .show();
}
```

The toast is shown right when the activity is shown, but when I select items in the spinner, the spinner dismisses and no toast is displayed again (not to mention the rest of the code in the callback fails to execute).

Any observations?

I really hope this something simple...

Comment: When I add more than one item to the list of items, they are clickable, but the very first one is not...

Comment: Im currently facing the same problem? Did you find a propper solution by now?

Comment: I've posted an answer to your question below.

Answer (score 1):

The spinner will only respond to ItemSelected events when a new item is selected. If there's only one item showing, you obviously can only reselect this one item in the dropdown list. That's the correct behaviour of the android spinner. onItemSelected will be fired if you have more than 1 item in your list, and if the clicked item is not the currently selected item.

From the android docs:

> public abstract void onItemSelected (AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
>
> Callback method to be invoked when an item in this view has been selected. This callback is invoked only when the newly selected position is different from the previously selected position or if there was no selected item.

Hope i could help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setOnItemClickListener() instead of setOnItemSelectedListener()?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.  Thanks anyway

Comment: Hmm... that's weird cause it's in the Android Documentation: 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: Wow, very weird...I'll continue to play with it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: A spinner does not support item click events. Calling this method will raise an exception.

Comment: From:  public void setOnItemClickListener (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l)

Answer (score 0):

If you have already the first item in the spinner selected and you want to "reselect" it (to fire the onItemSelected() callback) you can re-set the adapter by calling:

mMyTypeSpinner.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);

It may seem like a dull thing to do (since you have already set the adapter in onCreate()), but this little trick did work in my case.